# VOA Learning English Word Book is the correct word?

Tags: word-usage

I started studying English that used VOA Learning English.

The word book seems strange, so I ask.

First *"a (an) - advise"* What is mean? *a(an) = advise*

Next *"**about** - adj. almost ("about half"); of or having a relation to
("We talk about the weather")*

About is an adjective (adj)? Is not it an adverb (adv)?

[image]

[VOA Learning English Word Book.](http://docs.voanews.eu/en-US-LEARN/2014/02/15/7f8de955-596b-437c-ba40-a68ed754c348.pdf)

Is this word book correct?

Comment: I'd say this book is taking shortcuts. *About* can be an [adverb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/essential-british-english/about_2) or ap [preposition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/essential-american-english/about_1). To me it is a preposition in "we talk about the weather" and an adverb in "it's about half". Some say it is an adjective in the idiom "about to", but it is debated.

Comment: @Laure Ok thank you, I'll refer to the Help Center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"a (an) - advise** is not a bit of English, it's simply an index to the page. It says this page covers words from *a (an)* to *advise*.

As to **about** - you're right. The OED gives only one sense of *about* as an adjective, and marks that use as obsolete.

Comment: It's very nearly universal in dictionaries to have an indicator on each page for which words are covered on the page; there is even a phrase for it: they are called ***guide words***, and their presence allows you to find a specfic word in the dictionary much faster.